# Need to pass two element value on ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I create a program for giving appointments to the users. Date and time this is two different element.I save time dynamically to the database and user can select date and time. now i am create a Ajax request to match the date & time ! give it to any one or not.

```js
function Filter(str)
{
  var xmlhttp;    
  if (str=="")
  {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  }


  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari

    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

  xmlhttp.open("GET","filter.php?id="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control hide_date" value="" id="appoint" name="appoint" placeholder="Date" readonly>

<select type="select" name="appoint_time" class="form-control appoint_time" id="time-app" onchange="Filter(this.value)">
  <option value="">Time</option>                                            
  
<?php 
$sql5 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `id` FROM `time_slots` where `status` = '1'");
$query = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql5);
$solt_id = $query['id'];
$sql6 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `time` FROM `time_picker` where `time_slot` = '$solt_id'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql6))
{
?><option value="<?php echo $row['time']; ?>"><?php echo $row['time']; ?></option>
  <?php
}
?>
</select>
```

In this code the ajax work fine but and this only send appointment time value to filter page. I need to pass also the appointment date value to filter page. whenever i try it display empty. please tell how i use to both element value pass in one request.

Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vldwa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code will work when both element value received

```js
function Filter(str)
{
var xmlhttp;
var date=document.getElementById("appoint").value;
if (date=="")
  {
 document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
 return;
  }
if (str=="")
  {
 document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
 return;
  }
 

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
   document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","filter.php?id="+str+"&date="+date,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     <select type="select" name="appoint_time" class="form-control appoint_time" id="time-app" onchange="Filter(this.value,appoint.value)">
```

in script function

```
         function Filter(str,datz)                           

          xmlhttp.open("GET","filter.php?id="+str+"&date="+datz,true);
          xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: where from i'm you create user variable.

Answer (score 0):

**you can get value of date in this way**

```
var date=document.getElementById("appoint").value;
xmlhttp.open("GET","filter.php?id="+str+"&date="+date,true);
```